# Splitting a string at Space, except inside quotation marks

Tags: string, go

I was wondering if there is any way I could easily split a string at spaces, except when the space is inside quotation marks?

For example, changing

`Foo bar random "letters lol" stuff`

into

`Foo`, `bar`, `random`, `"letters lol"`, `stuff`

Answer (score 18):

Think about it. You have a string in comma separated values (CSV) file format, [RFC4180](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt), except that your separator, outside quote pairs, is a space (instead of a comma). For example,

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := `Foo bar random "letters lol" stuff`
    fmt.Printf("String:\n%q\n", s)

    // Split string
    r := csv.NewReader(strings.NewReader(s))
    r.Comma = ' ' // space
    fields, err := r.Read()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("\nFields:\n")
    for _, field := range fields {
        fmt.Printf("%q\n", field)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Ed4IV97L7H

Output:

```
String:
"Foo bar random \"letters lol\" stuff"

Fields:
"Foo"
"bar"
"random"
"letters lol"
"stuff"
```

Comment: That isn't the output I really wanted. I wanted, for example, the `letters lol` to be in quotation marks and the other not. Also, I didn't do a very good job with the question...
I was going to use it to split `blockdata 8539 58 584 {CustomName:"Foo"}` into `blockdata`, `8539`, `58`, `584`, `{CustomName:"Foo"}... Should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 14):

1. Using `strings.FieldsFunc` try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/-z3GWlF-NDJ):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := `Foo bar random "letters lol" stuff`
    quoted := false
    a := strings.FieldsFunc(s, func(r rune) bool {
        if r == '"' {
            quoted = !quoted
        }
        return !quoted && r == ' '
    })

    out := strings.Join(a, ", ")
    fmt.Println(out) // Foo, bar, random, "letters lol", stuff
}
```

---

2. Using simple `strings.Builder` and `range` over string and keeping or not keeping `"` at your will, try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/_Ozs21zvqny)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := `Foo bar random "letters lol" stuff`
    a := []string{}
    sb := &strings.Builder{}
    quoted := false
    for _, r := range s {
        if r == '"' {
            quoted = !quoted
            sb.WriteRune(r) // keep '"' otherwise comment this line
        } else if !quoted && r == ' ' {
            a = append(a, sb.String())
            sb.Reset()
        } else {
            sb.WriteRune(r)
        }
    }
    if sb.Len() > 0 {
        a = append(a, sb.String())
    }

    out := strings.Join(a, ", ")
    fmt.Println(out) // Foo, bar, random, "letters lol", stuff
    // not keep '"': // Foo, bar, random, letters lol, stuff
}
```

---

3. Using `scanner.Scanner`, try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/Pct3mj2VanX):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "text/scanner"
)

func main() {
    var s scanner.Scanner
    s.Init(strings.NewReader(`Foo bar random "letters lol" stuff`))
    slice := make([]string, 0, 5)
    tok := s.Scan()
    for tok != scanner.EOF {
        slice = append(slice, s.TokenText())
        tok = s.Scan()
    }
    out := strings.Join(slice, ", ")
    fmt.Println(out) // Foo, bar, random, "letters lol", stuff
}
```

---

4. Using `csv.NewReader` which **removes** `"` itself, try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/Ydk14neoIgh):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := `Foo bar random "letters lol" stuff`
    r := csv.NewReader(strings.NewReader(s))
    r.Comma = ' '
    record, err := r.Read()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    out := strings.Join(record, ", ")
    fmt.Println(out) // Foo, bar, random, letters lol, stuff
}
```

---

5. Using `regexp`, try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/UQyrvbDc9Eg):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := `Foo bar random "letters lol" stuff`

    r := regexp.MustCompile(`[^\s"]+|"([^"]*)"`)
    a := r.FindAllString(s, -1)

    out := strings.Join(a, ", ")
    fmt.Println(out) // Foo, bar, random, "letters lol", stuff
}
```

Comment: FieldsFunc contains this warning in the docs that make your first suggestion somewhat dangerous: 

"FieldsFunc makes no guarantees about the order in which it calls f(c) and assumes that f always returns the same value for a given c."

Comment: @BenMoss I see, that is somewhat strange! and I think out of character fot the Go programming language which is supposed to be no magic: but nevertheless till today Go 1.21.3 there is no magic and the loop for end, rune := range s { if f(rune) { means it is in order with the runes of the input string. I hope no one decides to spell a magic inside! otherwise we need to make a copy of FieldsFunc then!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

This ([go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/GgiBeIAAvD)) will cover all use cases for multiple words inside quotes and multiple quoted entries in your array:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    s := `Foo bar random "letters lol" stuff "also will" work on "multiple quoted stuff"`       
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`[^\s"']+|"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)`) 
    arr := r.FindAllString(s, -1)       
    fmt.Println("your array: ", arr)    
}
```

Output will be:

```
[Foo, bar, random, "letters lol", stuff, "also will", work, on, "multiple quoted stuff"]
```

If you want to learn more about regex here is a great SO answer with super handy resources at the end - [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759417/5674583)

Hope this helps

Comment: Seems like you only need: `[^\s"]+|"([^"]*)"`.  I guess the intent was to handle single quotes also, but that isn't in the test (and doesn't work due to missing `'` at the end).